# How to switch between tabs in Opera?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

This has got to be possible - I just don't see it: how do you change from one tab to another in Opera with the keyboard?

Comment: How are you doing it in other browsers?

Comment: Ctrl-Tab works in Firefox on the Mac, but not Opera. Oddly enough, as I found from looking around after John T's answer, on the Mac it's Option-Tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking for [keyboard shortcuts](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.51/en/keyboard.html), then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move to the next tab, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move to the previous tab.

Comment: Aha - that had been disabled somehow or other. Thanks :)

Comment: This still works with Opera Blink (Opera 15+).

Answer (score 9):

Under **Preferences -> Advanced -> Shortcuts** you can also enable single key shortcuts. You can then use 1 and 2 on your keyboard to cycle forward and backward through tabs.

Comment: Do this, it's really amazingly convenient. I have 1 & 2 mapped to buttons on the side of my mouse, I use it so much.

Comment: @Fake Name - I totally agree, I map the mouse left and right tilt-wheel buttons to switch to the left or right tab.

Comment: that's really handy! All the answers given are valid, but this one is cool :)

Comment: Be aware this only works on the older non-Chrome version of Opera. As far as I know the newer Opera doesn't support Ctrl+<1-9> for tab selection, nor custom keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use mouse gestures: Cycle through open tabs -> Hold right button, roll mouse wheel

Answer (score 1):

And on the Mac it's <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

(thanks [John T](https://superuser.com/questions/118934/how-to-switch-between-tabs-in-opera/118937#118937) for the pointer on where to look)

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler way is to use the key "2" to go to the next tab and the key "1" to go to the previous tab.

Works on Opera 9.63 (Build 2474 for Linux)

ps:  Though I wonder why it is the other way round on the [official documentation page](http://help.opera.com/Linux/9.01/en/keyboard.html)
(perhaps the version number is different but still...)

Comment: That's what John T said, too :0) http://superuser.com/questions/118934/how-to-switch-between-tabs-in-opera/118937#118937

Comment: This no longer works on Opera Blink (15+).

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> for prev tab and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> for nex tab.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no "Page Up" or "Page Down" key on macOS :)